# php5-fpm fails to start and leaves no log message

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

when run

```
sudo service php5-fpm start
```

from /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf:

```
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
log_level = debug
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
```

however

```
ls /var/run/php5-fpm.pid => not found
sudo tail /var/log/php5-fpm.log => no recent activity
```

any ideas on where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a poll definitions (worker)

[Wiki](http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Configuration_File)

[Example with comments](http://code.google.com/p/dnpm/source/browse/trunk/php5-fpm.conf.txt?spec=svn3&r=3#64)

Or, if you defined pools, test your configuration: sudo php5-fpm -t

Comment: the `sudo php5-fpm -t` pointed in the right direction.  thanks!